# retrieving xml node from multiple raws

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I retreieved a column using inner join on two tables:

```
SELECT Table_1.*, Table_2.c
FROM
Table_1
inner JOIN
Table_2 ON CHARINDEX(Table_2.a, Table_1.b) > 0 and Table_2.c=1
where Table_1.d like '%xxx...%'
```

One of the column in the above query is type XML:

```
<column1>
---------
<XML1>
---------
<XML2>
---------
<XML3>
---------
.
.
.
```

1.I want to retrieve a string from each XML and to display it as additional column in the query (all xml structure are identical)?
thanks.
Lets say the XML is as follow:

```
<root>
 <row>
  <String>XXX...</String>
 </row>
</root>
```

Comment: What have **you** tried?

Comment: I know how to do it on one raw but I want to do it on all the raws.

Comment: Can you post your sample xml data and expected output ?

Comment: I posted the query in a seperate answer- see below.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22302470/569436) answer not what you are looking for?

Comment: I edited the original question and detailed, please look .

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I assume the column of your table contain xml of below format.

```
<root>
  <row>
    <value>1</value>
  </row>
</root>
```

Then check below query.

```
SELECT  b.ID,
       x.XmlCol.value('value[1]', 'int') AS [NodeVal] 
FROM   YourTable b
CROSS APPLY b.ActualXmlCol.nodes('/root/row') x(XmlCol);
```